# Does EsLint have a rule to make sure key and value of object in the same line?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Looking for a rule (can't seem to find anything, might've just missed it) in EsLint to basically prefer something like this:

```
const example = {
    a: 
    5
};
```

vs something like this:

```
const example = {
    a: 5
};
```

I hope the rule can check if the key and value not in the same line.

I tried to add a rule named "object-curly-newline" and my setting looks like:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "object-curly-newline": [
            "error",
            {
                "ObjectExpression": "always",
                "ObjectPattern": {
                    "multiline": true
                },
                "ImportDeclaration": "never",
                "ExportDeclaration": {
                    "multiline": true,
                    "minProperties": 3
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work in my case.

Thanks in advance!